# Retrieving model id in integration testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

I am doing some `rails` integration testing.

```
describe "project wizzard", js: true do
  before(:each) do
    @project = FactoryGirl.build(:project)
    visit new_project_path
  end
it "going through wizard steps, the, submitting" do
    fill_in "project[title]", with: @project.title
    click_button  "Submit"
    ...
  end
end
```

when the user clicks, I want to check if the model was created, so how can I do that and how can I retrieve the `id`of this model ?

Comment: Model creation should go in model specs, in Request spec, you could check the response, for example: `response.body.should include(@project.title)` if you have the created project's title in the response page.

Comment: @vee `Model creation should go in model specs`or `Model creation must go in model specs` ? you mean it is not possible to retrieve this information ? Btw, I get this message error `undefined local variable or method `response'`

Comment: Model creation must go in model spec.  Capybara is used for simulating end user interaction with your application.  To help this, imagine this test to be a manual test where you'd type in the url to your application on a browser and fill in the project title.  What would you expect in response for this test?  There are ways you could include the created instance in the response, for example a hidden HTML element with created project's id and check for that.  This however is not the correct approach to testing persistence, hence the reason for "should" instead of "must".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what I usually do is check for the data after submmit it

```
expect(Model.last.attr).to eql 'something'
```

In your case could be

```
expect(Project.last.title).to eql 'title'
```

And to be sure it has been saved

```
expect(Project.count).to eql 1
```